# Laravel - Do Logic in config/database.php

Tags: database, laravel, config

As you all know, in Laravel `config/database.php` is bunch of `arrays` and `values`. But for certain condition, I need to do some logic there and I manage to do some simple logic in `config/database.php` and it is working as what I want (can refer the code below), but I'm wondering is it fine/practical to do like this?

If it is not practical, can you suggest what is the other way to get the same result as below?

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => (function(){ 
        $config = [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'live_db'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myuser'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '2309423234'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => 'gn_',
            //'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', null),
        ]; 

        // do some logic here (and it's working!!)
        // but........
        // is it okay to do like this?
        if(env('DB_WITH_SSLMODE', false)){
            $config += [
                'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
                'options'   => [
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA', 'C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\server-ca.pem'),
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT    => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT', 'C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\client-cert.pem'),
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY', 'C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\client-key.pem'),
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT', false)
                ],
            ];
        }

        return $config;
    })(),

],
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using ternary operator? (almost like it's done by default in laravel 5.8).

**Note: The first solution doesn't remove the sslmode from the config array. If you need to do so, just go with the second option!**

1) It should work like this:

```php
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'sslmode' => env('DB_WITH_SSLMODE') ? env('DB_SSLMODE','prefer') : null,
        'options' => (extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') && env('DB_WITH_SSLMODE')) ? [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT'),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY'),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT')
        ] : [],
    ],
],
```

or

2) *dirty solution* but with one conditional:

```php
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => array_merge([
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null
    ], (extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') && env('DB_WITH_SSLMODE')) ? [
        'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
        'options' => [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT'),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY'),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT')
        ]
    ] : [ 'options' => [] ]),
],
```

Then move the default values you had in env() to your .env file (note that I removed the **DB_OPT_** prefix):

```
DB_WITH_SSLMODE=true
MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA=C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\server-ca.pem
MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\client-cert.pem
MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY=C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\client-key.pem
MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT=false
```

So if you set **DB_WITH_SSLMODE** to false, an empty array would be returned and ssl would not be enabled.

**Note:** I think the **sslmode** you specified is needed only for PostgreSQL connections, which is not your case.

Comment: what about `'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),`?? where to put it?

Comment: Read the note at the bottom of the answer: it should be needed only for PostgreSQL connections. If you try that config it should work anyways

Comment: actually i need it... in my live server, if i remove the `sslmode`, there will be error displayed.... so I need the `sslmode`..

Comment: in my `live server` i need to turn on the SSL...but in my localhost, i need to turn OFF the SSL... trust me, the first solution is not working... i tried already... if i want to disable SSL, i must remove the `sslmode` property...if i dont remove it and if i just make it blank value (e.g `'sslmode'=>''`), it will raise error..

but however, the dirty(2nd) solution is working... thanks for sharing....i upvoted your answer..

Comment: Okay, I thought later that you needed to remove completely the solution. if that's the case the second solution is the way to go.

Comment: Used solution 1 successfully. Now I can use a single connection to support my local and dev/staging/production environments.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service provider for this:

```
class SSLServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Kernel $kernel)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $config = \Config::get('database.connections.mysql');

        if (env('DB_WITH_SSLMODE', false)) {
            $config += [
                'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
                'options' => [
                    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA',
                        'C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\server-ca.pem'),
                    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT',
                        'C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\client-cert.pem'),
                    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY',
                        'C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\client-key.pem'),
                    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT', false)
                ],
            ];
        }

        \Config::set('database.connections.mysql', $config);

    }

}
```

and don't forget to register your service provider in config/app.php

```
App\Providers\SSLServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: new knowledge for me...thanks...i'm sure it's working but i still feel this answer is not practical....so i cannot mark your answer...but i upvote this answer....thanks for sharing this...

Comment: Do not use any env() call other than in config files because if you enable configuration caching (`php artisan optimize/php artisan config:cache`) any env call outside the configuration folder will return an empty value.

Comment: @mdexp ,,, yeah, that make sense...it means this answer is not suitable if we use `config:cache`...right?

Comment: Right, it's also stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#configuration-caching)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can also do something as simple as:

```
$database = [
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'live_db'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myuser'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '2309423234'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => 'gn_',
            //'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', null),
        ]
    ]
];

if(env('DB_WITH_SSLMODE', false)){
    $database['connections']['mysql'] += [
        'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
        'options'   => [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA', 'C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\server-ca.pem'),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT    => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT', 'C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\client-cert.pem'),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY', 'C:\wamp64\bin\cloudsql\certificates\client-key.pem'),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => env('DB_OPT_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT', false)
        ]
    ];
}

return $database;
```